# C# cannot run delete statements using ODBC Oracle

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odbc

Very strange error where running a delete statement of any kind causes a Invalid Statement exception.

My query is `delete from table where Id = 1`. Id is not a primary key. There are several delete statements which I need to run as well which do not use primary keys. Exact same statement runs on toad.

Connection String :

```
<add name="Oracle_xxxxx" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*host*)(PORT=*port*))(CONNECT_DATA=
(SID=*sid*)));Uid=*uid*;Pwd=*pwd*;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

Queries run fine. I don't really want to change the connection string / driver if possible.

Error message :

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.HandleError(OdbcHandle hrHandle, RetCode retcode)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String
method, Boolean needReader, Object[] methodArguments, SQL_API odbcApiMethod)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String  
method, Boolean needReader)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
at ClientOnBoarding.COBTrackerDataManager.*function*() in C:\Working\SVN\xx\App_Code\xx.cs:line 928

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit : I ran ExecuteNonQuery() first, then tested ExecuteReader() and both gave me the same error - apologies for the misleading error message above.

Edit 2 : I've tried and tested my SQLs on Toad multiple times with no issue. My update and insert statements all work absolutely fine with or without the trailing semicolon. Only delete was giving me an exception.

Edit 3 :

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("@delete from table where Id = " + param, conn);
//conn is OdbcConnection object with valid connection I use for all other commands. Conn is open. param is a string (which is a number)
try
{
    //cmd.ExecuteReader();//was testing both
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}//end try
catch (Exception e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}//end catch
```

Comment: how are you executing the query ? Are you using `ExecuteNonQuery();` and how are you building it.

Comment: Check if Procedural Option is installed.

Comment: What @Habib.OSU said!  Looking at the stack trace it looks like you're calling `ExecuteReader`.  Try changing that to `ExecuteNonQuery` and see if that changes your results.

Comment: Post the C# code connect to the query.

Comment: I apologize - i ran ExecuteNonQuery() first, then tested  ExecuteReader() and both gave me the same error. The error you see above is the same for both.

Comment: Can you post the code that builds and runs the delete statement? Do you log in as the same user in TOAD as you do when you run this code?

Comment: have added the code that builds and runs the statement. Yes the login is the same.

Answer (score 1):

From error message looks like it is a sql statement error, nothing to do with .NET. Try running this query directly in oracle. Also, I think in Oracle you need ";" in the end `delete from table where Id = 1;`, also make sure Id or table name is not a keyword

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Id and table are both definitely not keywords and the command runs perfectly fine on Toad with or without the trailing semicolon. As in my edit, I've tested all my queries on Toad and all my inserts and updates work fine. Only the delete is giving me the exception. I'm worried it might be a driver thing?

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys feel like an idiot ... the @ sign was after the quote instead of before ...

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("@delete from table where Id = " + param, conn);
```

Should be

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(@"delete from table where Id = " + param, conn);
```